# Line Chart vertical grid lines only for aggregated values (days, instead of hours)

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, time, axis, grid

I have two columns: day of week, hours (for each day) and number of things occurring on each hour of a specific day of week.

Below an example with first two days:

[image: Days,hours,things]

I want to plot these data as a line chart where on the horizontal axis I only show the days (hours would make it too overcrowded), and I want to show in the grid the vertical lines for the days (start and end) and the day name (on the axis) should be centered between its too lines.

Below what I managed to get so far, by having the horizontal axis refer only to days:

[image]

As you can see the vertical lines are denser than needed, one for each record (on for each hour) instead of one for each day. Moreover I struggle to get the day name centered, it rests on the left.

Comment: Have you tried formatting the major gridlines to match with the days? (right-click on the axis labels and choose "Format Axis" from the dropdown menu

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad I accessed the Format Axis menu but I really cannot find any option to help with any of my points (Vertical grid lines only for days and day label properly centered in its range). They seem to be pretty easy configurations, but Excel is making them difficult (or impossible) to me.
Did you try with the sample data that I posted?

Answer (score 0):

Format the axis (select the axis and press Ctrl+1).

Under Tick Marks > Interval Between Ticks, change 1 to 24. This affects how many major gridlines you get.

You still get all the labels but only as few gridlines as you want.